# How can i parse ANTLR rule for complex numbers with ambiguous token reference to DIGIT?

Tags: floating-point, antlr4, grammar, complex-numbers

I have the following ANTLR rule to parse `float` complex numbers where the floats can be written as such :

- 3
- 3.0
- 3. 
- 3f

And the `float` and `i` should be interchangeable (e.g. float i | i float)

Here's the ANTLR grammar rule (it's ugly, i know, it's all in 1 line):

```
floatComplex : SUB? (DIGIT+ 'f'|DIGIT+ DOT? (DIGIT+)?) (ADD|SUB) (I (DIGIT+ 'f'|DIGIT* DOT? (DIGIT+)?) | (DIGIT+ 'f'|DIGIT+ DOT? (DIGIT+)?) I)

DIGIT : [0-9] ;
ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;
DOT : '.' ;
I : 'i' ;
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve each number specifically, does anyone have any idea how ? Because `ctx.DIGIT()` returns a list of all the digits combined right ? not each part specifically =o and then i'm not sure how to retrieve all digits before a `.` or a `+` or `-` sign etc..

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated

Comment: How about +-inf and nans? These are floats and eg 17.0+iInf  is a complex number

Comment: @dmuir i think for + and - `inf` can be added as tokens inside NUMBER and UNSIGNED lexer rules

Comment: Another thing you might want to allow for is floats printed in hex. For example C has the %a format specifier; if you print say 2647.0/1024.0 with this you get 0x1.4aep+1. Although not many people would type such numbers in, they could well occur in files generated by a program. They have the advantage of being a direct representation of the binary, and so do not suffer from rounding issues.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this way is much easier since i can just call `ctx.NUMBER()` or `ctx.UNSIGNED()` to check if they're given :

```
// Parser rules
complexAtom : NUMBER? EXP POW (I UNSIGNED?|UNSIGNED I)  # PolarComplex
    | NUMBER? CIS UNSIGNED                              # CisComplex
    | (NUMBER (ADD|SUB))? (I UNSIGNED?|UNSIGNED I)      # Complex
    ;

// Lexer rules
NUMBER : INT 
    | FLOAT 
    ;
UNSIGNED: DIGIT+ 'f'        
    | DIGIT+ DOT (DIGIT+)?
    | DIGIT+
    ;
INT : SUB? DIGIT+ ;
FLOAT : INT DOT (DIGIT+)?
    | INT 'f' 
    ;
DIGIT : [0-9] ;
EXP: [Ee] ;
ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;
POW : '^' ;
DOT : '.' ;
CIS : 'cis' ;
I : 'i' ;

WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

EDIT : I also figured out how to let the lexer parse directly into `COMPLEX` tokens (and eventually i can manage the actual parsing in the visitor code) using  the following lexer grammar :

```
// Lexer grammar
COMPLEX : SUB? IMAGINARY
    | NUMBER (ADD|SUB) IMAGINARY
    ;
POLAR_COMPLEX : NUMBER? EXP POW IMAGINARY ; 
CIS_COMPLEX : NUMBER? CIS UNSIGNED ;

UFLOAT : UINT (DOT UINT? | 'f') ;
FLOAT : SUB UFLOAT ;
UINT : DIGITS ;
INT : SUB UINT ;

CIS : 'cis' ;
IM : 'I' ;
ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;
POW : '^' ;
DOT : '.' ;
EXP : [Ee] ;
DIGITS : DIGIT+ ;
DIGIT : [0-9] ;

fragment IMAGINARY : IM UNSIGNED? 
    | UNSIGNED IM
    ;
fragment NUMBER : UFLOAT
    | FLOAT
    | UINT
    | INT
    ;
fragment UNSIGNED : UFLOAT 
    | UINT 
    ;

WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The lexer returns a token with type and text. It does not partition up the complex number into parts like the parser. Thus, you moved the rule to the parser. But, if white space is in the grammar but not allowed between tokens for the rule, you would also need to check for that to be complete. But, most don't worry about this detail.

Comment: Oh yeaah i'm sorry, let me add it right now for complete-ness sake, i actually have a WS lexer rule to skip whitespaces. But thanks for confirming as i wasn't sure at all still if this is the best way